# How to split column of characters into numerical levels in R?

Tags: r

`age <- "60 - 69"`

I have a column of data that has ages listed as characters in ranges like the example above. I need to convert to the column of ages into numeric levels. Is there a function in R to do this?

Comment: You mean convert the column into factor?

Comment: In R, a categorical variable is called a "factor" variable.  Each of the N values of the categorical variable belongs to one of K categories (or levels).  Usually, you have a lot of values (N is big) and only a handful of categories (K is small).  If `age` is a character variable, you can convert it to a categorical/factor variable with `as.factor(age)`.  One free online resource to learn more is [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html).

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: For your sample input, `age <- "60 - 69"`, what ouput do you expect? `60`? `69`? `65`? `1`, because it's first age group occurring in your data? `1` because it's the lowest ages in your data?

Answer (score 0):

Use `separate` to split the character string into pieces.

```
library(tidyverse)

ages <- c("10 - 19",
          "20 - 29",
          "30 - 39")

tibble(ages = ages) %>% 
    separate(ages, into = c("lower", "upper")) %>% 
    mutate(across(c(lower, upper), as.integer))
```